# converting a int variable to a string and passing as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a variable "StudentID" which is an int, I need to convert to a string then pass it to string as a string.

This is what I have so far:

```
int StuID = Convert.ToString("StudentID");

string ReturnXML = "<Student=\"StuID\" />";
```

So if the "StudentID" variable were equal to 12345, I need the ReturnXML to look like this:

```
<Student="12345">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: <Student="12345"> is not valid xml, it should be <Student ID="12345">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty to alter the XML a bit, to make it valid.

```
int studentId = 42;
string returnXml = string.Format(@"<Student id=""{0}"" />", studentId);
// returnXml will be '<Student id="42" />'
```

If you want the `Student` element itself to have the student id value, you probably want to put the value inside the element:

```
string returnXml = string.Format(@"<Student>{0}</Student>", studentId);
// returnXml will be '<Student>42</Student>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework I don't want to give you the answer directly, however, look at `Int32.ToString()` for the string conversion. To build the return XML please look up `String.Format()` function.

Comment: +1 for not actually giving a solution; I missed the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an int to an Xml Element like this:

```
XElement student = new XElement("Student", new XAttribute("Id", stuId));
string returnXml = student.ToString();
// returnXml will be '<Student Id="42" />'
```

Your XML is not valid, I added an Id tag. The advantage of XElement versus the string format in the other answers is, that you can create complex xml-trees and use queries to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use string.Format:

```
int stuId = 12345;
var returnXml = string.Format("<Student id=\"{0}\" />", stuId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string StuID = StudentID.ToString();

string ReturnXML = "<Student=\"" + StuID + "\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace variable name with its value, you can do

```
int stuId = 1;
string ReturnXML = string.Format("<Student=\"{0}\" />",stuId.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
string StuID = StudentID.ToString();

string ReturnXML = "<Student ID=\"" + StuID + "\" />";
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all! ToString returns a string, not an int. You better use string format like in the other samples than add strings with +.

Comment: @slfan: it's supposed to be a string, I put int as the type of StuID by mistake.